# Chrome text rendering different when same page is inside an iframe

Tags: css, google-chrome

Does anyone notice a difference in subpixel rendering when the exact same page is displayed inside an  iframe? and how can this be matched.

[image]

Top: Iframe

Bottom: No iframe

I'm asking because some fonts appear to be slightly blurry in an iframe. There's no transforms applied on the iframe whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. It turned out that when you don't set a background color for `<body>`, subsampling is turned off and regular antialiasing is activated (which doesn't look as good).

All you have to do is `body{ background: white; }` for the subsampling to always activate.